# Converting MSpec tests to plain NUnit

Tags: tdd, comparison, nunit, bdd, mspec

I am trying to get started with pure TDD and also consider the BDD flavor. I am trying to grasp, how writing unit tests with MSpec feels in contrast pure to NUnit.

Consider a simple MSpec test like the following:

```
[Subject("PersonRepository")]
class when_adding_a_new_person
{
     Establish context = () => sut = new PersonRepository();

     Because of = () => sut.AddPerson("Jim", "Panse");

     It should_have_a_person = sut.Count.ShouldEqual(1);
     It should_have_that_persion = sut.Contains("Jim", "Panse");

     static PersonRepository;
}
```

How would you convert this to NUnit in a clean way but without using any BDD extensions or anything. I think that it is a good idea that each should assertion to be one separately runnable test and `Establish` and  `Because` should be executed just once for all should assertions. I could use `[Setup]` for `Establish` and  `Because`, but that would be run for each test. I could use `Assert.` for `It` but that wouldn't make them separately runnable tests.

How would this example contrast to NUnit style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I generally would recommend against converting from MSpec to NUnit. When introducing people to MSpec I like to start with a "classic" NUnit (`PersonRepositoryTester.TestAddNewPerson`) fixture, convert it over to a more BDDish fixture like the one below and then show them how MSpec can help to reduce language noise and introduce readability + better reporting.

```
[TestFixture]
public class When_adding_a_new_person
{
    PersonRepository sut;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Establish_and_because()
    {
        sut = new PersonRepository();

        sut.AddPerson("Jim", "Panse");  
    }

    [Test]
    public void It_should_have_one_person()
    {
        Assert.That(sut.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
    }

    [Test]
    public void It_should_contain_the_new_person()
    {
        Assert.That(sut.Contains("Jim", "Panse"), Is.True);
    }
}
```